# Pybrain error: function buildNetwork() is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, neural-network, nameerror, pybrain

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and PyBrain 0.3 (installed via pip). I can't reproduce the "quickstart" code there is in PyBrain documentation pages because the function buildNetwork() seems to not be defined and it triggers a NameError. Here is the code:

```
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer

ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)
ds.addSample((0, 0), (0,))
ds.addSample((0, 1), (1,))
ds.addSample((1, 0), (1,))
ds.addSample((1, 1), (0,))

# here is the problem \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
net = buildNetwork(2, 3, 1, bias=True, hiddenclass=TanhLayer)

trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
trainer.train()

net.activate([0, 0])
net.activate([0, 1])
net.activate([1, 0])
net.activate([1, 1])
```

And this is the error message I receive when trying to run this script:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d45aee0605fb> in <module>()
----> 1 net = buildNetwork(2, 3, 1, bias=True, hiddenclass=TanhLayer)

NameError: name 'buildNetwork' is not defined
```

It's strange because all previous lines don't trigger any errors, the problem is occurring with buildNetwork() function. Could someone please help me?

Comment: give me a link about doc of this module.

Comment: Sure. This code is a mix of QuickStart section, parts 2 and 3: pybrain.org/docs/#quickstart

Comment: I think Cilyan answered you...

Comment: Yes, but there are other import dependencies and I don't know how to search which module should I import in order to meet some specific dependency, like "Tanhlayer" now :/

Comment: use `dir(modulename)`

Comment: dir(module) will just list what there is inside a module. I'm looking for a search that do it backwards: you input the function or feature you need and it outputs the corresponding module you need to import in order to use this function or feature.

Comment: I think it works : http://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you forgot to import that function:

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
```

See [documentation](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/network.html?highlight=buildnetwork#the-buildnetwork-shortcut).

Each time you want to use a special member of a module, you have to import it. Look at the documentation and search the member. [For example for TanhLayer](http://pybrain.org/docs/api/structure/modules.html?highlight=tanhlayer#pybrain.structure.modules.TanhLayer). You see that the function is in `pybrain.structure.modules`. So you have to import it like

```
from pybrain.structure.modules import TanhLayer
# or
from pybrain.structure.modules import *
```

There are other (sometimes cleaner) ways to import functions. [This document](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) from effbot explains nicely what are the differences and which you should use.